# What frequency ranges are best for speakers?

Tags: acoustics, noise, ultrasound

I have two speakers, one is a 6-inch speaker and another one is Peavy PR 10 (Large speaker). What frequency ranges are best suited for each of the speakers and why?

Comment: You should really consult the manufacturers for specifications. The ability of a complete speaker depends on many things among which are the driver's specifications (apparent mass, total compliance, resonance frequency, impedance, etc.), box's dimensions, apparent volume, material and a lot more. It's not easy to know what frequencies suit best your speaker. There are 15" speakers that are tuned to work as subwoofers while at the same time other 15" speakers act as the low and/or mid-frequency parts of a larger system.

Answer (score 4):

the rule of thumb for *engineers* is as follows: a speaker cone radiates best at frequencies where the wavelength is roughly equal to the cone diameter. the wavelength of a 1000hz tone is about one foot so a ten inch speaker will radiate well at about 1200Hz. The six inch speaker will "come on" at about 2000Hz.

How *low* in frequency a given speaker can go below the rule-of-thumb point depends on the design of the *enclosure* it is mounted in. How *high* it can go above the rule-of-thumb point depends on the *cone mass*.

How *loud* it can play depends on the allowable *cone excursion*.